# Why does login shell launched by tmux modify the PATH in an unexpected manner?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, tmux

On my macOS Sierra 10.12.6, I have my `~/.bash_profile` as shown below.

```
macbookpro:~ lone$ echo $TERM_PROGRAM
Apple_Terminal
macbookpro:~ lone$ cat ~/.bash_profile
echo 1: PATH: $PATH
PATH=BEG:$PATH:END
echo 2: PATH: $PATH
```

I do not have `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

```
macbookpro:~ lone$ ls -ld ~/.bash*
-rw-------  1 lone  CORP\Domain Users   6875 Jan 12 19:05 /Users/lone/.bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 lone  CORP\Domain Users     59 Jan 12 19:05 /Users/lone/.bash_profile
drwx------  3 lone  CORP\Domain Users    102 Jan 12 19:06 /Users/lone/.bash_sessions
macbookpro:~ lone$ ls -l ~/.profile
ls: /Users/lone/.profile: No such file or directory
```

When I launch a new terminal, I get this output, which is expected.

```
Last login: Fri Jan 12 11:02:56 on ttys000
1: PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
2: PATH: BEG:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:END
macbookpro:~ lone$ rm -rf ~/.bash_sessions/
```

Now if I run tmux in this terminal, I get this output, in the tmux pane after it starts.

```
1: PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:BEG:END
2: PATH: BEG:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:BEG:END:END
macbookpro:~ lone$
```

Why does the first line show `BEG:END` in the end? I was expecting it to have `BEG` in the beginning and `END` in the end just like in the case of launching a terminal.

Comment: Check `/etc/bashrc /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc` etc.

Comment: don't forget this site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer. The `/etc/profile` file looks like this.

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

The clue is this command invocation in this startup file.

```
/usr/libexec/path_helper -s
```

Let me remove `~/.bash_profile` and simulate the startup sequence.

```
macbookpro:~ lone$ rm ~/.bash_profile
macbookpro:~ lone$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
macbookpro:~ lone$ ls /etc/paths.d/
macbookpro:~ lone$ /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"; export PATH;
```

So what we see so far is that `path_helper` takes the paths in `/etc/paths` and returns a path string that `/etc/profile` takes and `eval`uates to define the `PATH` variable.

Let us see what happens when we have redefined `PATH` variable to `BEG:$PATH:END` ourselves (to simulate we had done earlier in `~/.bash_profile`).

```
macbookpro:~ lone$ PATH=BEG:$PATH:END
macbookpro:~ lone$ echo $PATH
BEG:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:END
macbookpro:~ lone$ /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:BEG:END"; export PATH;
```

So `path_helper` appears to construct the `PATH` in the following manner:

1. Pick all paths from `/etc/paths`.

   ```
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
   ```
2. Append the current `PATH`.

   ```
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:BEG:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:END
   ```
3. Cleanup the `PATH` by removing duplicates.

   ```
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:BEG::END
   ```

Comment: Great answer! For me, after removing duplicate items in PATH, only one `:` is left between `BEG` and `END`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed on Centos that if you set the environment variable in, say, .profile and then run tmux then tmux stores this information. So even if later you change the path and remove some of the PATH then tmu still keeps this information.

I finally figured out that tmux creates some sort of tmux profile against the userid (tmux-) in /tmp. I deleted this directory and then ran tmux and the old path was removed.